# How to find last BTS information on Android?

Tags: android, gsm, cellid

I want to use last BTS info for find location when GSM signal Disconnected.

Is this information saved in a file or database I can read and find the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See bellow link for ServiceState class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html